# Quick and dirty android module creation without using Eclipse IDE to build jar files

Tags: android, dynamic, jar, module, executable

I am currently developing an android application that allows me to dynamically load modules.
Therefore I can have as many modules as I like, and my main application just needs to load them.

I've managed to make this work for the most part - but I want to create an executable to "speed up" the module creation process, or even just find a way to simplify the steps involved.

To create a module I currently have to do the following:

1. Build the android project containing the files required for my
   module [none of which are activity classes - so I don't have to
   worry about the androidmanifest file at all]
2. Use the eclipse IDE jar creation tool to select which src files I want to be compiled into .class to put into my jar, and specify my own custom manifest file for this jar, as well as package all the images I use for the module into the jar as well.
3. Then using the jar file I run the dex creator command on it to generate a .dex file from the class files contained in the jar, and then use the aapt command to push the dex file back into the jar file.
4. At this point the jar(Now its a module) is created and I can put it on the server for downloading, download the modules in my app and load all the code I need in my app using reflection.

I have looked into building with ant. It looks fairly complicated for what I wish to achieve and I'm not quite sure where to start with it.

I obviously can't use simple javac to compile my java files contained in my module src because all that code makes references to the android sdk as well as a static library shared between my main application and my respective module.

Currently I use the Eclipse IDE to create the inital jar with all my packaged images, class files, manifest, and then I use two separate batch files that call on the android-sdk to create dex and push the dex into the jar.

Can I simplify this process in one easy step instead? Or is trying to do this - a whole project on its own?

Answer (score 0):

> I have looked into building with ant. It looks fairly complicated for what I wish to achieve and I'm not quite sure where to start with it.

[The documentation for Ant](http://ant.apache.org) is online, as is [the documentation for building Android projects with An](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-cmdline.html)t. The only difference is that you will want to add a `<jar>` task to your Ant `build.xml` file, as I have done in several projects, such as [this one](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless):

```
<target name="jar" depends="debug">
    <jar
        destfile="bin/CWAC-EndlessAdapter.jar"
        basedir="bin/classes"
    />
</target>
```

You are also welcome to consider Maven. While I do not use Maven personally, it has many fans and community-driven Android support.

You are also welcome to write your own build script in any programming language that suits your fancy: Java, Ruby, Perl, Python, etc.

> I obviously can't use simple javac to compile my java files contained in my module src because all that code makes references to the android sdk as well as a static library shared between my main application and my respective module.

Every Android IDE, and Ant, and Maven, and so on, "use simple javac to compile [an Android project's] java files". They simply add the appropriate Android SDK JAR file to the build path.